# Исключение в регулярном выражении

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть регулярное выражение:

```
/лох/i
```

Как исключить отсюда слово **переполох**?

Comment: а лоханку, всполох и тд?

Comment: @splash58, да, в идеале тоже

Answer (score 2, accepted):

если нужно найти только определенное слово, можно поставить в начале и в конце `\b` - символ, означающий границу слова и добавить u - модификатор, означающий, что это unicode

```
/\bлох\b/iu
```